# Javascript - How to construct objects of one class in another class

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript.

I have a class for playing cards:

```
class Card {
    constructor(color, number)  {
...
```

And another class named 'Line' that needs to be constructed with a 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 cards. How do I make the constructor so I can use the card objects in the Line class?

```
class Line {
    constructor() {
```

So I can use this command:
    const line1 = new Line(new Card(...), new Card(...))

Thank you.

Comment: import the Card class?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I would recommend to pass an array of cards to the `Line` constructor, not multiple arguments

Answer (score 2):

Let it take a spread argument and put that into a property:

```
 class Line {
   constructor(...cards) {
      this.cards = cards;
   }
 }
```

So you can do:

```
 const line = new Line(
   new Card(),
   new Card()
 );

 console.log(line.cards[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

Card:

```
'use strict';

export default class Card {
  constructor(color, number)  {
...
```

Line:

```
'use strict';

const Card = require('/path/to/card');

export default class Line {
  cards = [];

  constructor(cards) { // <- Array of cards objects
    this.cards = cards.map(c => new Card(c.color, c.number));
  }
...
```

Usage:

```
const line = new Line([
  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 1
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    number: 2
  },
  ...
]);
```